# Help me choose section title

Tags: publications, titles

I finished writing a paper and I'm currently putting finishing touches, but I'm finding it difficult to choose a good title for the first section.

Basically this section is written for a lay audience and talks about how the research was conducted and how I ended up discovering the main result. It includes lots of motivation, any pitfalls I encountered, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not concern academia as defined by the help center.

Comment: I think its a very lazy question, but not off topic.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, such a section is called "Introduction" or "Motivation."